# Conditional statements in a class, but outside of scope of the function

Tags: python, class, scope, conditional-statements

We know that with notation:

```
class Foo(object):

    a = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 2

    def c(self):
        print('c')
```

we can create static variable `Foo.a`, 'normal' variable `b`, which will be available after creating and instance of `Foo`, and method `c`

Today I was really surprised, that I can use conditional statements in a class, but outside of scope of the function

```
class C():
    if True:
         a = 1
    b = 2
```

Languages like C++/Java, taught me that legal notation is similar to:

```
class Name():
    variable = <expression>
```

Could you describe other rules, which refer to this specific scope? How I should name this scope?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The class body is *just Python code*. It has specific scope rules, but anything goes otherwise. This means you can create functions conditionally:

```
class C:
    if some_condition:
        def optional_method(self):
            pass
```

or pull methods from elsewhere:

```
import some_module

class D:
    method_name = some_module.function_that_accepts_self
```

etc.

The Python documentation for [`class` definitions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) states:

> A class definition is an executable statement.

and

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see section [*Naming and binding*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)), using a newly created local namespace and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains only function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved. A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary.

Note the *usually* in that text. Essentially, the class body is executed as a function would, and anything you put in the body namespace becomes an attribute on the class.

The [*Naming and binding*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming) section then tells you:

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods

so names you define in this block cannot be directly accessed in methods; you'd use `class.name` or `self.name` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In java everything is `classes` and `object`, `classes` are container but in python everything is `object`.
`Classes` are also `objects`. like `functions(also objects)` so when you use conditional statement in function then python allows you to do same in Classes.

like:-

```
def A():
   if condition:
      do something
   elif condition:
      do somethig
   else:
      do something
```

is same

```
Class A()
   if condition:
      do something
   elif condition:
      do somethig
   else:
      do something
```

you can assign functions even to store in a variable like you do for classes

```
def A():
    pass

a = A # is valid
```

while in java you can't define function outside the classes.