# Statements outside of methods but inside classes

Tags: python, class

So recently I found out you can do things like this in python:

```
class Foo():
    for x in range(10):
        pass
```

In what way writing statements like for or while loops, if-else blocks, etc *inside a class but outside of a method* is useful and is it even a good programming practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional statements in a class, but outside of scope of the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230680/conditional-statements-in-a-class-but-outside-of-scope-of-the-function)

Comment: This code is executed at the same time the class is defined.  That can be useful.